# I'm using ngbootstrap. Bydefault first tab is active. But I want 2nd tab need to be active instead of first

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

When using ng-bootstrap with angular it's working fine. I'm not getting how to enable TAB SECOND as by default activated when page is loaded. Thank you.

```
<nav ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">
    <ng-container ngbNavItem>
        <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
         <ng-template ngbNavContent>
          Om
       </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container ngbNavItem>
       <a ngbNavLink>Two</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
        Namaha
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container ngbNavItem>
       <a ngbNavLink>Three</a>
       <ng-template ngbNavContent>
        Shivaya
       </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you ?

Answer (score 9):

Use `[(activeId)]="active"`  and assign values to your navItem like following `[ngbNavItem]="1"`

**`component.html`**

```
<nav ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-tabs">
    <ng-container [ngbNavItem]="1">
        <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            Om
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container [ngbNavItem]="2">
        <a ngbNavLink>Two</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            Namaha
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container [ngbNavItem]="3">
        <a ngbNavLink>Three</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            Shivaya
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</nav>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="mt-2"></div>
```

**`component.ts`**

```
activeId:any = 2;
```

Here's the working **stackblitz**: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lg1sot-gn4bek?file=src/app/nav-basic.html**

Comment: Sateesh Thank you for your reply. I'm able to see that the tab2 is opening on page loaded. But why content is not displaying for that tab2. Even after clicking the tab1 OR tab3 it's changing and content is not displaying. any idea.

Comment: updated the answer need to use ngbNavOutlet to see the content

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that. Thank your

Comment: Thanks, helped me for getting the id of active tab in typescript